# Is this MacBook Pro battery dangerous?

Tags: battery

This is an old MacBook Pro battery.

[image: battery]

I started having trouble with the battery, so I took it out.  It later turned into what you see.  It's since been sitting on a shelf in my house for almost a year without changing noticably.

Is it dangerous, or is it something I can dispose of at my leisure? (you don't need to tell me that I can't just put it in general waste)

Comment: It's probably one of the explosive ones Apple had [recalled](http://www.engadget.com/2006/07/31/apple-initiates-macbook-pro-battery-recall-program/) a few years back.

Comment: Hmm, you may be half-right.  It's from a 17".  This link seems relevant: http://www.wwco.com/~wls/blog/2007/07/18/new-apple-battery-defect-model-a1189/ Looks like I'm not alone; I should have googled the model number from the battery case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its bloated, contains lithium, and [could catch fire](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fG_UuPmLO1c), which would be VERY bad. I'd say, get rid of it as soon as possible in case something does happen.